# how to perform ETL in map/reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

how do we design mapper/reducer if I have to transform a text file line-by-line into another text file.

I wrote a simple map/reduce programs which did a small transformation but the requirement is a bit more elaborate below are the details:

- the file is usually structured like this - the first row contains a comma separated list of column names. Second and the rest of the rows specify values against the columns
- In some rows the trailing column values might be missing ex: if there are 15 columns then values might be specified only for the first 10 columns.
- I have about 5 input files which I need to transform and aggregate into one file. the transformations are specific to each of the 5 input files.
- How do I pass contextual information like file name to the mapper/reducer program?
- Transformations are specific to columns so how do I remember the columns mentioned in the first row and then correlate and transform values in rows?

Comment: You really need to provide more details if you want a relevant answer. Transforming text file to another text file matches pretty much most map\reduces out there...

Answer (score 5):

Split file into lines, transform (map) each line in parallel, join (reduce) the resulting lines into one file?

Comment: I wrote a simple map/reduce programs which did a small transformation but below are further challenges that I am facing:the file is usually structured like this - the first row contains a comma separated list of column names. Second and the rest of the row specify values against the columns.In some rows the trailing column values might be missing ex: if there are 15 columns then values might be specified only for the first 10 columns.

Comment: I  have about 5 input files which I need to transform and aggregate into one file. the transformations are specific to the input file. How do I pass contextual information like file name to the mapper/reducer program? Transformations are specific to columns so how do I remember the columns mentioned in the first row and then correlate and transform values in rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can not rely on the column info in the first row. If your file is larger than a HDFS block, your file will be broken into multiple splits and each split handed to a different mapper. In that case, only the mapper receiving the first split will receive the first row with column info and the rest won't.

I would suggest passing file specific meta data in separate file and distribute it as side data.  Your mapper or reducer tasks could read the meta data file.

Through the Hadoop Context object, you can get hold of the name of the file being processed by a mapper. Between all these, I think you have all the context information you are referring to and you can do file specific transformation. Even though the transformation logic is different for different files, the mapper output needs to have the same format.

If you using reducer, you could set the number of reducers to one, to force all output to aggregate to one file.